# How I could install HtmlPurifier in my custom module?

Tags: adminhtml, magento2.4, security

I made my own form:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">customer_form.customer_form_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Blogpost Actions</item>
        <item name="reverseMetadataMerge" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <buttons>
            <button name="save" class="MageGuide\FirstModule\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\SaveButton"/>
            <button name="back" class="MageGuide\FirstModule\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\BackButton"/>
        </buttons>
        <layout>
            <navContainerName>content</navContainerName>
            <type>tabs</type>
        </layout>
        <deps>
            <dep>add_blogpost.blogpost_data_source</dep>
        </deps>
    </settings>
    <fieldset name="blogpost">
        <settings>
            <label translate="true">Blog Post</label>
        </settings>
        <field name="blog_post_id" formElement="input">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">blogpost_data_source</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </field>
        <field name="title" formElement="input">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">blogpost_data_source</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <label>Title</label>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <visible>true</visible>
            </settings>
        </field>

        <field name="content" sortOrder="10" formElement="wysiwyg" template="ui/form/field">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">page</item>
                    <item name="wysiwygConfigData" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="is_pagebuilder_enabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="toggle_button" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="height" xsi:type="string">200px</item>
                        <item name="add_variables" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="add_widgets" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="add_images" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="add_directives" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <label translate="true">Contents</label>
                <dataScope>content</dataScope>
            </settings>
            <formElements>
                <wysiwyg>
                    <settings>
                        <rows>5</rows>
                        <wysiwyg>true</wysiwyg>
                    </settings>
                </wysiwyg>
            </formElements>
        </field>

    </fieldset>

    <dataSource name="blogpost_data_source">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <submitUrl path="*/*/save"/>
        </settings>
        <dataProvider
            class="MageGuide\FirstModule\Model\BlogPost\DataProvider"
            name="blogpost_data_source">
            <settings>
                <requestFieldName>id</requestFieldName>
                <primaryFieldName>blog_post_id</primaryFieldName>
            </settings>
        </dataProvider>
    </dataSource>
</form>
```

And my own Controller that handles the `*/*/save` path:

```
<?php

namespace MageGuide\FirstModule\Controller\Adminhtml\BlogpostForm;

use MageGuide\FirstModule\Model\BlogPost;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Save extends Action
{
    protected BlogPost $blogPostModel;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        BlogPost $blogPostModel
    ) {
        $this->blogPostModel = $blogPostModel;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        var_dump($data);
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());

        if(empty($data)){
            return $resultRedirect;
        }

        if(isset($data['blogpost'])){
            $data=$data['blogpost'];
        }

        $this->blogPostModel->setTitle($data['title']);
        $this->blogPostModel->setContent($data['content']);

        try{
            $this->blogPostModel->save();
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('The data has been saved.'));
            $resultRedirect->setUrl('adminblogposts/index/index');
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('Something went wrong while saving the data.'));
        } finally {
            return $resultRedirect;
        }
    }

    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

But at my Model I want to use the HtmlPurifier (Known approach for XSS cleanuip for Rich text editors) at method `setContent`:

```
namespace MageGuide\FirstModule\Model;

use MageGuide\FirstModule\Model\ResourceModel\BlogPostResource;
class BlogPost extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(BlogPostResource::class);
    }

    public function getSkus():array
    {
        $skus=$this->getData('skus')??"";
        $skus=explode(',',$skus);
        $skus=array_map('trim',$skus);
        $skus=array_filter($skus);
        return $skus;
    }

    public function setTitle(string $title)
    {
        return $this->setData('title',strip_tags($title));
    }

    public function setTitle(?string $content)
    {
        // Use Html Purifier here
        return $this->setData('content',$content);
    }

}
```

But in order to do so I have to install it via:

```
composer require ezyang/htmlpurifier
```

Is that reccomended to do so upon common `./vendor` where also magento resides?

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** Yes.

**Long answer:**

Composer keeps all third party packages under `./vendor`, that includes HtmlPurifier that you wish to install. It is highly recommended that packages be installed using this method, so yes, you can be sure that you're doing it right.

FYI, in case you have not known, Magento 2 is already set up with Autoloading Standard (see [PSR-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/)). That means, as long as the packages locate inside `./vendor`, you can use them like Magento core modules, no issues or further configurations needed.

Happy coding!